# electron-packager excludes .obj model files in built application

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I'm building an Electron application, and testing out the `electron-packager` library. When I simply run `electron-packager .`, I get the expected build, save for the fact that none of my .obj model files are included in the build. Their parent directories as well as sibling files are included in the build, just not the .obj files.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: So I actually just looked into the `electron-packager` code, and for whatever reason, they ignore files that have the `.obj` file extension. Looking into why now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those in the future, the `electron-packager` module is written for both Windows and Unix systems. During the .exe compilation process, Windows generates `.obj` files. Since this is the case, `electron-packager` has added `.obj` files to the file `ignore.js`, which thereby prevents `.obj` 3d models from being included in resulting binaries.

[See this issue on GitHub conversation here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/pull/491)

Here is the relevant code from the `ignore.js` file in the `electron-packager` module:

```
const DEFAULT_IGNORES = [
  '/node_modules/electron($|/)',
  '/node_modules/electron-prebuilt($|/)',
  '/node_modules/electron-packager($|/)',
  '/\\.git($|/)',
  '/node_modules/\\.bin($|/)',
  '\\.o(bj)?$'
]
```

If you're using .obj files, comment out this the .obj line from the array and you're good to go. I've been doing this for two weeks without consequence on both Windows and Linux machines.